# How to set a user input as default text for a Tkinter Entry widget in another frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two frames to switch around. In each frame, there is an `Entry` box. How do I set my input in the first `Entry` box in the first frame as the default text for the second `Entry` box in the second frame?

```
from tkinter import *


class Root(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("PageOne")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def quit(self):
        self.destroy()

text = ''


class PageOne(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        global text

        entry_box_1 = Entry(self, width=40)
        entry_box_1.pack()
        text = entry_box_1.get()

        quit_button = Button(self, text="Quit Program",
                    command=lambda: controller.quit())
        next_button = Button(self, text="Next",
                    command=lambda: controller.show_frame('PageTwo'))

        next_button.pack()
        quit_button.pack()


class PageTwo(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        entry_box_2 = Entry(self, width=40)
        entry_box_2.insert(END, text)
        entry_box_2.pack()

        quit_button = Button(self, text="Quit Program",
                            command=lambda: controller.quit())
        back_button = Button(self, text="Back",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))

        back_button.pack()
        quit_button.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Root()
    root.mainloop()
```

My second `Entry` box keeps being blank when I switch to the second frame.

Comment: ***"set my input in the first Entry ... for the second Entry box"***: Either you use a [`trace(mode, callback) `](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) callback or implement a `def do_update(...`, which is called on every `Frame` switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing the `PageTwo` frame when `text` variable is an empty string and while you are switching to this frame you are not inserting any value to `entry_box_2`.

I suggest you to invoke the `insert` method every time you are switching to the `PageTwo` frame. You can do this by creating a new switching method that can be similar to `show_frame_with_default_text` method in the following code.

```
from tkinter import *


class Root(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("PageOne")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def show_frame_with_default_text(self, page_name, text):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.entry_box.delete(0, END)
        frame.entry_box.insert(0, text)
        frame.tkraise()

    def quit(self):
        self.destroy()


class PageOne(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        entry_box_1 = Entry(self, width=40)
        entry_box_1.pack()

        quit_button = Button(self, text="Quit Program",
                    command=lambda: controller.quit())
        next_button = Button(self, text="Next",
                    command=lambda: controller.show_frame_with_default_text('PageTwo', entry_box_1.get()))

        next_button.pack()
        quit_button.pack()


class PageTwo(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.entry_box = Entry(self, width=40)
        self.entry_box.pack()

        quit_button = Button(self, text="Quit Program",
                            command=lambda: controller.quit())
        back_button = Button(self, text="Back",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))

        back_button.pack()
        quit_button.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Root()
    root.mainloop()
```